# How to download simple html (tables and images) into pdf using jspdf?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to download html document into pdf landscape format using jspdf. My document has tables and images in it.
I think I am missing some extensions of jspdf which are causing errors.
Please edit my code snippet to generate successful pdf file.
Here is jsPDF Code

```
<script src="JQueries/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    source = $('#download')[0];
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, { // y coord
            'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }, margins
    );
}
```

I have downloaded my html document into pdf format using chromes print and download in pdf option manually. Which is 100% same as html document. I need to make it downloadable using JavaScript that my clients can easily download it on single click.

```js
    function demoFromHTML() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        source = $('#download')[0];
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }, margins
        );
    }
```

```css
 #challan_data
 {
  display:none;
 }
 .containerChallan
 {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: calibri;
 }
 .innerChallan
 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 #original,#duplicate,#triplicate,#fourth_copy
 {
  width:25%;
 }
 .optional
 {
  color:green;
 }
 .headerMono
 {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-geometric-technological-background_1055-1907.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 81px;
  background-position: top;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
 #challan_no
 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline;
  background: black;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
 .challanDigitsP1
 {
  display: table-cell;
  color:#FFF;
  background-color:grey;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
 }
 .challanDigitsP2
 {
  display: table-cell;
  color:#FFF;
  background-color:#333;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
 }
 .mini_note
 {
  font-size: 60%;
 }
 .cell_contents
 {
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a id="clickbind" href="javascript:demoFromHTML();">Download PDF</a>
  <br>
  <table id="download" align="center" border="1" width="1267px" class="containerChallan">
   <tr>
    <td id="original">
<table border="1" width="100%" class="innerChallan">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" class="headerMono">
   <span class="ch_title">BANK<BR>COPY</span>
   <br><br><br>
   Challan No. 
   <div id="challan_no">
    <span id="chno_1" class="challanDigitsP1">A</span>
    <span id="chno_2" class="challanDigitsP1">9</span>
    <span id="chno_3" class="challanDigitsP1">0</span>
    <span id="chno_4" class="challanDigitsP1">7</span>
    <span id="chno_5" class="challanDigitsP1">1</span>
    <span id="chno_6" class="challanDigitsP1">7</span>
    <span id="chno_7" class="challanDigitsP2">1</span>
    <span id="chno_8" class="challanDigitsP2">2</span>
    <span id="chno_9" class="challanDigitsP2">3</span>
    <span id="chno_10" class="challanDigitsP2">4</span>
   </div>
   <br>
   <span class="mini_note">(For Credit to Collection Account of The Behya University of Indiana)</span> <br>Account No: <b>00327901156907</b>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="39%" class="cell_contents">Name</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><b><span id="ch_name">Adam</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell_contents">Father's Name</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_f_name">xyz</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell_contents">CNIC No</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_cnic">3120268882285</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell_contents">Address</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_address">Street No. 1, Model Town A, Bahawalpur</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell_contents">Challan Category</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_main_cat">Cat-1</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell_contents">Challan Purpose</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_sub_cat">p1</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hide_on_demand">
  <td class="cell_contents">Department</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_department">Computer Science</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hide_on_demand">
  <td class="cell_contents">Session</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_session">2016-18</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hide_on_demand">
  <td class="cell_contents">Semester</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_semester">1st</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="hide_on_demand">
  <td class="cell_contents">Program</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><span id="ch_program">MCS</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell_contents">Amount</td>
  <td class="cell_contents"><b><span id="ch_amount">Rs. 2500/-</span></b></td>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <td colspan="2" class="cell_contents">
   <span style="float:left; margin-left:15px;margin-top: 28px;">Sign Officer</span><span style="float:right; margin-right:15px;margin-top: 28px;">Sign Cashier</span>
   
   <div class="mini_note" style="display:table; margin:0 auto; font-style:italic;margin-top: 80px;">Challan Generation Date and Time : <span id="date_time">dd:mm:yyyy, ss:mm:hh</span></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

    </td>
    <td id="duplicate">

    </td>
    <td id="triplicate">

    </td>
    <td id="fourth_copy">

    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  
<script>
 document.getElementById("duplicate").innerHTML = 
 document.getElementById("triplicate").innerHTML = 
 document.getElementById("fourth_copy").innerHTML = 
 document.getElementById("original").innerHTML;
 document.getElementsByClassName("ch_title")[1].innerHTML = "STUDENT<br>COPY";
 document.getElementsByClassName("ch_title")[2].innerHTML = "TREASURER<br>COPY";
 document.getElementsByClassName("ch_title")[3].innerHTML = "DIRECTOR IT<br>COPY";
</script>
```